# Real-time Matplotlib animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, time, matplotlib-animation

I was trying to animate the motion of a spinning top on Matplotlib but I'm having problems with the time it lasts being the one I solved the equations of motion for. The part of the code used to make the GIF is the following:

```py
final_time = 7*np.pi/10
temps = np.linspace(0, final_time, 800)

x1 = 10.77 # length from origin to highest point of top
Z_cm = 3.91 # length from origin to top's center of mass 

x_top = x1 * np.sin(theta) * np.sin(phi)
y_top = -x1 * np.sin(theta) * np.cos(phi)
z_top = x1 * np.cos(theta)

x_top_cm = Z_cm * np.sin(theta) * np.sin(phi)
y_top_cm = -Z_cm * np.sin(theta) * np.cos(phi)
z_top_cm = Z_cm * np.cos(theta)

xtop_anim = []
ytop_anim = []
ztop_anim = []

xtopcm_anim = []
ytopcm_anim = []
ztopcm_anim = []

def update(i):
  ax.cla()

  xtop_anim.append(x_top[i*5])
  ytop_anim.append(y_top[i*5])
  ztop_anim.append(z_top[i*5])

  xtopcm_anim.append(x_top_cm[i*5])
  ytopcm_anim.append(y_top_cm[i*5])
  ztopcm_anim.append(z_top_cm[i*5])

  ax.scatter(x_top[i*5], y_top[i*5], z_top[i*5], s=15, marker='o',c='r')
  ax.plot(xtop_anim, ytop_anim, ztop_anim, "k", linewidth=1)
  ax.scatter(x_top_cm[i*5], y_top_cm[i*5], z_top_cm[i*5], s=10, marker='o',c='r')
  ax.plot(xtopcm_anim, ytopcm_anim, ztopcm_anim, "r", linewidth=1)
  ax.plot([0,x_top[i*5]], [0,y_top[i*5]], [0,z_top[i*5]], color='k', linewidth=0.6)
  ax.scatter(0, 0, 0, c='k',s=5)

  ax.set_xlim3d(-x1, x1)
  ax.set_ylim3d(-x1, x1)
  ax.set_zlim3d(0, x1)

fig = plt.figure(dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

anim = FuncAnimation(fig = fig, func = update, frames = round(len(temps)/5), interval = 1000/30, repeat = False)

anim.save('traj.gif', writer='pillow', fps=30)
Image(open('traj.gif', 'rb').read())
```

You can download the .npy files that correspond to each angles' arrays here: https://github.com/jsgf04/Spinning-top . Just use `np.load('name of the file.npy')` to import them. These arrays have length 800 like time.

The GIF it outputted is this one:
[image]

As you can observe, it lasts a bit more than the more or less 2 seconds (7*π/10 seconds) it is supposed to last.

In this case, what I tried was modifying the GIF's fps (usually switching it to 30 or 60), the number of frames (proportional to the length of the time linear space), their interval, the animate function's variable i (multiplying it by some number to skip frames) and changing the time's length (basically reducing it). I couldn't manage to make it faster than the animation above. Furthermore, the inconvienient with a faster animation is that detail about the top's trajectory is lost therefore it'd be good to keep it as it is or enhance it in the measure of possible.

Comment: Not necessarily related, but you could save the frames yourself, in whatever time resolution, and join them yourself with ffmpeg later. Might be more flexible

Comment: Seems like the most plausible and satisfying solution. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The current code cannot be run as is (there are missing imports and variable definitions).

Comment: Shall I define x1 and Z_cm and provide the data arrays for psi, phi and theta?

Comment: @JoanSGF Yes, provide everything necessary to run your code.

Comment: @jared Done, sorry for delay.